# Excel VBA slow to delete column unless document saved first

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with the speed of code that deletes columns.  The code below takes 5 seconds to run, if I save the document right before running it then it only takes 1 second.  The savings isn't great but I have a decent computer and others that run this sheet are basically on thin clients and I have much more code to run.  Also when the workbook is completed, I am not able to save as it is used as a template and saved as a new workbook when completed.  The number of rows with data is ~49,000 and I have tried this without `ClearContents` first as well.

Is there any way to speed this up without having to save the document first?

```
Sub GenerateOperations()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .CutCopyMode = False
End With

Dim OpSheet As Worksheet

Set OpSheet = Sheet3

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
OpSheet.Range("A:C,E:G,L:Q").ClearContents
OpSheet.Range("A:C,E:G,L:Q").Delete xlShiftToLeft
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that by finding the last row and only deleting that section of the column that the code runs almost instantaneously, working code is below.

```
Sub GenerateOperations()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .CutCopyMode = False
End With

Dim OpSheet As Worksheet

Set OpSheet = Sheet3

With OpSheet
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    .Range("A1:C" & LastRow & ",E1:G" & LastRow & ",L1:Q" & LastRow).Delete xlShiftToLeft
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without this bit : `.ScreenUpdating = True` ?

Comment: why would he turn that off? It is highly recommended to switch screen updating off in order to increase performance

Comment: That wouldn't speed it up

Comment: Yes turning it off speeds it up. Turning it back on in my experience is unnecessary and can slow the code if another sub is called immediately after.

Comment: If you don't turn it back on then Excel gets to the point where the screen doesn't update or do anything at all...

Comment: Also, you could hide the columns instead of deleting them? You have already cleared the contents so just unhide to populate next time. Its faster than deleting and shifting all the other columns to the left.

Comment: @tjb1 Do you have any sample workbook with that issue?  Never come across that in the time ive done vba. And if that's the case, then the timing of turning it on is what you need to consider. You could turn it off on workbook open and turn it back on after all subs have run or on workbook close.

Comment: I have nothing I can share but the last time I checked this workbook is running ~1700 lines of code and when building it I found that after working on it a while it starts to act up no matter what you do and requires a restart of Excel.

Comment: That's a beast ! :)

Comment: Probably best suited to be built in something else at this point but no other options right now.